# Звезда Полынь. Почему так называется?

Tags: значение-слов

Думаю, все знают строчки из Откровения Иоанна Богослова: «*Третий Ангел вострубил, и упала с неба большая звезда, горящая подобно светильнику, и пала на третью часть рек и на источники вод. Имя сей звезде «полынь»; и третья часть вод сделалась полынью, и многие из людей умерли от вод, потому что они стали горьки»*.
В свое время многие связывали это описание с Чернобыльской катастрофой, но мы сейчас не будем вдаваться в эти рассуждения. Просто интересно, почему звезда так странно названа? Что имелось в виду?

Comment: "Чернобыль" образована от одного из видов ПОЛЫНИ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет тут никакого мистического значение (ну, помимо того, что скрыто в самом "Откровении"). Полынь, полоть - родственно "пламя", восходит к общеславянскому морфу со значением "гореть".
"Звезда Полынь" - яркая, "горящая" звезда.

А само слово "полынь" (трава), видимо, связано с горьким вкусом, от которого во рту все горит. Но она съедобная. Травой этой действительно питались в лихие годы.

Comment: Уважаемый, в голодные годы питались не полынью, а лебедой.

Comment: Полынный хлеб - вещь известная. Кое-где ели и просто вареную полынь.
То, что ели лебеду, никак не исключает того, что ели полынь.

Answer (score 2):

ОТКРОВЕНИЕ ИОАННА в церковно-славянской редакции переводилось с греческого. Надо проверить по оригинальному греческому тексту, как там обозначена эта ЗВЕЗДА, а уж потом строить предположения. Вспомните в Евангелии изречение Иисуса: "Легче верблюду пройти через игольное ушко, чем богатому войти в Царствие Небесное." По-гречески слова ВЕРБЛЮД и КАНАТ пишутся одинаково. Ясно, что тут плохой перевод - по реальному смыслу, имелся в виду КАНАТ, а не ВЕРБЛЮД. В случае со ЗВЕЗДОЙ ПОЛЫНЬ возможен такой же плохой перевод, -   нужно сначала  проверить исходный греческий оригинал. Я греческим языком не владею, и мне такое не под силу...

Comment: канат, веревка, ремень  -греческий- ΣΧΟΙΝΙ, 
σκοινί, 
ζώνη   верблюд ΚΑΜΗΛΑ, то бишm САМЕl       это в современном.
его нет в древнегреческом, что странно,но!!
в древнегреческом, действительно
κάμῑλος--толстая веревка, канат, что тоже очень странно. А еще более странно  КАМИЛАВКА.Первоначально — это шапка из верблюжьей (греч. κάμηλος) шерсти, которую носили в странах Ближнего Востока для защиты от солнца (отсюда и название).
И скорее дело не в переводе.
А травка наводит на грустные мысли, что полынь--с полыньей связана, и впечатлениями.

Answer (score 0):

Это же "откровения". Очень поэтический текст, насыщенный большим количеством метафор. Да ещё и с претензией на пророчество.
Трудно сказать, почему пророки выбирают то или иное слово. Но обычно это диктуется "видениями" или "божьей волей" (пророк уверен, что не имеет права заменить слово, пришедшее ему на ум). А уж разбирать ассоциативные цепочки, пришедшие в голову человеку, жившему 2 тысячи лет назад...

Comment: Что значит "с претензией"? Я прошу уважать религиозные чувства присутствующих тут!

Comment: Пророчество можно считать таковым только если оно сбылось. Вне зависимости от религиозных чувств.

Comment: Слово "претензия", на мой вкус, само по себе не содержит негативной контаминации и уж тем более никак не оскорбляет религиозных чувств.  
  
А вот объяснение greydog'а меня скорее разочаровало. Во-первых,
 вопрос был о значении слова, а не о выборе его в том или ином контексте. А, во-вторых, скорее уж намек на якобы несбывшееся Откровение может как-то зацепить верующего.  
Правда, у нас свобода совести, которую таки никто не отменял...

Comment: Никогда не ел полынный хлеб, а на лебеде вырос, сохранился. А уж у нас, на Дону, полыни! Ешь - не хочу!

Answer (score 0):

*Полынь обыкновенная, чернобыльник, чорнобиль* (укр.) - это всё разные названия одного и того же растения...
Может, все-таки речь шла не о растении, а о месте происшествия? А при переводе решили, что имеется в виду трава, и перевели как полынь, а не чернобыль.
Стоит ли при этом искать какие-то другие возможные толкования слова "полынь"?

Comment: «Может, все-таки речь шла не о растении, а о месте происшествия?» Конечно. Место происшествия — планета.

Answer (score 0):

*Полынь* — адаптированная для простого ума *Горечь*. Звезда по имени Полынь — великая, безмерная горечь. Ударила повально по всему грешному человечеству смертью каждого третьего, так что потерю в семье испытал всякий переболевший и выживший. Ощутимое предупреждение, способствующее через скорбь отойти от «веселья» и жить по Заповедям, всего лишь. Никакой мистики, разумеется.

Comment: Кроме, как (Апок. 8,11), есть (Иерем. XXIII.15): Аз напитаю их пелынем и напою их желчию. Полный ЦСС даёт пелынь как переносное значение горькой участи и страшного бедствия. Там же продолжение: в греческих текстах вместо пелыни стоят скорбь, страдание, неволя, насилие (слав. — теснота).

Answer (score 0):

***Полынь-звездой*** в старину называли самую яркую звезду на небосклоне — *Сириус А* (Полынь — это звезда, которая ярко светит, пылает). Второе название Сириуса, которое встречается в древности, — ***собачья звезда*,** так как она находится в созвездии Большого Пса.
В Откровении Иоанна Богослова "Имя сей звезде «полынь»" — это метафора. Смысл ее на современный язык переводится как взрыв атомной бомбы, от радиации которой погибнут многие люди и будут заражены реки.
Иоанн был ясновидящим. Но, во-первых, само *Откровение* писалось зашифрованным языком. Во-вторых, как бы увидел человек того времени, две тысячи лет назад, взрыв атомной бомбы, современный самолет, скоростные поезда и т.д.? Только **о**бразами того времени! Самолет — это железная птица, поезд — это железная змея, бомба — это яркая звезда и т.д.
Кого интересует тема и значение символов *Откровения*, рекомендую книги:
И.Ньютон — "Замечания на книгу пророка Даниила и апокалипсис св. Иоанна", 1915; Н.Морозов — "Откровение в грозе и буре", 1907.

Comment: Списать «во вторых, итд., 1915г.» на шок, или общую загруженность?

Comment: А что Вас так удивило, shampar? Это годы издания этих книг на русском языке, ошибки никакой нет.

Comment: Неграмотность общая и небрежность в наборе. Притом, что редактор отмечает спорные моменты.

Comment: Я ответил на вопрос - "звезда полынь, почему так называется", а не грамотность в наборе свою пришёл демонстрировать.) Зрите в корень shampar!

Comment: На работе не столь много времени, чтобы успевать еще на свою небрежность в наборе обращать внимание.)

Comment: Не тратьте время на пустое комментирование, а поправьте свой текст, и все будут смотреть в корень, не отвлекаясь на крону.